# React: resources are not loaded correctly for some routes

Tags: reactjs, apache, react-router

I have a react application with some routes, for example:

- /home
- /faq
- /profile/1
- /post/title-of-post-id-1

All works fine when url have just 1 level (/home, /faq, ecc).

For urls that have 2 or more levels (/profile/1 or /post/title-of-post-id-1) happens that the *index.html* file are loaded correctly *but related resources* (js,css) cannot be loaded because the browser sends to server a request with wrong path i.e.

```
GET http://HOST/profile/resources/js/main.js
```

instead of

```
GET http://HOST/resources/js/main.js
```

The applications loads route with this code:

```
 <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
     {Object.keys(loadableRoutes).map(path => {
         const { exact, ...props } = loadableRoutes[path]
         props.exact = exact === void 0 || exact || false // set true as default
         return <Route key={path} path={path} {...props} />
     })}
```

and

```
const loadableRoutes = {

    '/home': {
     component: loadable(() => import('/Home/homepage.js')),
     },
     '/profile/:uid': {
          component: loadable(() => import('/Profile/profile.js')),
          exact: true,
      }, 
      '/post/:posId': {
          component: loadable(() => import('/Post/post.js')),
          exact: true,
      },
```

How I can indicate the correct "basename" attribute for these urls?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved issue adding this line to "index.html":

```
<base href="/">
```